# Jquery Remove from onclick inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this simple code

```html
<div id="adic">hello world</div>
<span onclick='jQuery.remove("#adic")'>DEL</span><br>
```

I want only remove div with id adic,but if use onclick don´t works, i don´t know if howewer i put some bad or howewer i do something wrong, because if use ths function in script and call script, works but from inside onclick inside span for remove other div, no works

Thank´s in advanced

Comment: try with `jQuery("#adic").remove()`

Comment: You are using jQuery incorrectly. Use `$("#adic").remove()`. [Look here for more information](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Without jquery:

`function removeDiv(id) {
    div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div)
}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :`$("#adic").remove()`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adic">hello world</div>


<span onclick='$("#adic").remove()'>DEL</span><br>
```